# Solr web crawl not indexing 301 redirects

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

I am trying to index a website with **Apache Solr v6.0.1**. Solr generally indexing properly but skipping the 301 redirects with a *warning*.

I am using the following command to index a site, i.e.

```
post -c getting-started https://example.com -recursive 5 -delay 1
```

And it results the following:

```
Entering crawl at level 1 (118 links total, 117 new)
SimplePostTool: WARNING: The URL https://example.com/help/guides returned a HTTP result status of 301
```

I confirmed that the 301 redirect pages aren't being crawled from  Solr admin query tool.

Is there any configuration change that I need to do to follow 301 redirect URLs?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot head scratching, it's better to use Nutch to index into Solr and it's quite easy really. Follow step-by-step tutorial from Apache:

**Nutch 1.x**
https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial

**Nutch 2x**
https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Tutorial